# Using python with Anaconda in Windows

Tags: python, windows, numpy, cmd, anaconda

I have just installed Anaconda on my computer because I need to use Numpy.
Well, when I use python I for some reason have to be in the same folder as `python.exe` and, of course, now that I want to use Anaconda I have to be in the `Anaconda3\Scripts` folder where `python.exe` isn't. This is a nightmare, how can I use anaconda with python on a windows computer? Why does it have to be so complicated?

Comment: just open up `spyder` which is an IDE, which is installed when you install anaconda.

Comment: @shivsn Proposing OP to use an IDE when he/she wants to use the command line is not constructive.

Comment: @mwormser He says that he wants to use Anaconda with Python, not that he wants to use the command line. The easiest way to do that is by using Spyder.

Comment: @Forzaa In that case I would recommend using [PyCharm](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration#pycharm) instead of Spyder. I made the transition myself and do not want to go back.

Comment: I should have specified that I want to use the command line. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

I think you are referring to the command-line use of `python`?

If you have admin priviliges on your machine you can add `python` to your environment variables, making it available in the console anywhere. (Sorry for different spellings, I am not on an english machine)

1. Press `Shift+Pause` ("System")
2. Click "Advanced System Options"
3. Click "Environment variables"
4. In the lower field with "System variables" there is a variable called `PATH`. Append the complete path to your `python.exe`  without the file to that by adding a `;` behind the last path in the variable and then adding your path. Do not add any spaces!

Example: `C:\examplepath\;C:\Python27\`

Comment: You can create a `PATH` variable in the user environment variables, without requiring administrator access. At logon it gets concatenated to the end of the system `PATH`. The entries don't need a trailing backslash and preferably shouldn't have one since it wastes valuable space. Older versions of Windows (IIRC up to Windows 7) cap the combined system + user `PATH` at 1000 characters.

Comment: I get prompted with an admin-login when I try to access the environment variables. How can you change them user-specifically without admin login?

Comment: The control panel's "user accounts" has a task to change just the user's environment variables. However it's broken in Windows 10. Clicking on it does nothing. Instead you can open a command prompt and run `setx PATH "C:\examplepath;C:\Python27"`. Confirm that it was set for the current user by running `reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH`. To see the new `PATH` value, run a new command prompt from Explorer.

Comment: You should run `reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH` beforehand to get the existing user value to pass to `setx`, so as to not overwrite it. You could also do all of this in Python using `_winreg` (or 3.x `winreg`), but `setx` broadcasts a message to Explorer that makes it reload the environment, which avoids having to log off to see the new value. Broadcasting this message in Python requires ctypes or PyWin32.

Answer (score 3):

When you install anaconda on windows now, it doesn't automatically add Python or Conda to your path.

If you don’t know where your conda and/or python is, you type the following commands into your anaconda prompt (it comes when you install anaconda)

[image]

Next, you can add **Python and Conda** to your path by using the setx command in your command prompt.
[image]

Next close that command prompt and open a new one. You should now be able to use the python command. To do this you open a command prompt and type

python nameofPythonfile.py

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444

Answer (score -3):

To be able to do that in the command line you just have to add Python and also the Anaconda3\Scripts directory to your system path.

Here is a good tutorial on setting your path in Windows:
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm